# Understanding the output of seqefsub

Tags: r, traminer

I have a dataset where I have three columns containing the site name, the event and the time. An example of it is shown below:

```
ABC123      Event A        25-07-21 00:01
ABC123      Event B        25-07-21 00:01
```

The output of `seqecreate` is:

`[1] 1-(Event A,Event B)`

And the output of `seqefsub` gives me:

```
sequences1                           support     count  
(Event A)                               1         1      
(Event A,Event B)                       1         1      
(Event B)                               1         1
```

However, I want only one output which would be the **(Event A,Event B)**. Is there a way to change the `seqefsub` parameters?

Comment: Hi Syed Zarar and welcome to the site :)
it is much easier to help you out if you supply us with some data and expected output, do you want the time difference between the time of eventA and eventB?

Comment: Hi Jagge, so basically instead of getting three sequences (Event A, EventA-EventB, Event B), I want to only get event A-event B. Does that clarify and answer your question?\

Answer (score 0):

With the function `seqentrans` from `TraMineRextras` you can add the number `ntrans`of transitions and the number `nevent` of events to the data table returned by `seqefsub`. Using these values you can then select the subsequences you want.

I illustrate using your example with 1 as timestamps for the two events.

```
library(TraMineRextras)
tse <- read.table(header=FALSE,text="
                  ABC123 1 A
                  ABC123 1 B
                 ")
names(tse) <- c("id", "timestamp", "event")
## id must be integer
tse[,1] <- as.integer(as.factor(tse[,1]))
tse
#   id timestamp event
# 1  1         1     A
# 2  1         1     B

## creating the event sequence object
(eseq <- seqecreate(tse))
# [1] 1-(A,B)

## extracting subsequences
subs <- seqefsub(eseq, min.support = 1)
## adding counts of transitions and events
(subs <- seqentrans(subs))
#   Subsequence Support Count ntrans nevent
# 1         (A)       1     1      1      1
# 2       (A,B)       1     1      1      2
# 3         (B)       1     1      1      1

## Displaying only subsequences with at least two events
subs[subs$data$nevent >= 2]
#   Subsequence Support Count ntrans nevent
# 1       (A,B)       1     1      1      2
```

Comment: Hi Gilbert, that helps a ton but I have another problem, my data also has instances where only a single event sequence has to be created or even where a single + multiple event sequences are needed. e.g I have 7 events A, B, A, B, C, C, A and the final event should be A-B (x2), C (x2), A (x1). Is there a way to solve this? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This could be handled by using `seqeconstraints` to select the suitable counting method and window size. If you need more details, please post it as a new question.